# injected singleton into stateless bean is null

Tags: null, ejb, javabeans, code-injection, stateless

I have a Singleton EJB that I'm trying to inject into an Stateless bean, that's also a WS endpoint (Jersey).

The injected singleton is always null.

The project is packed as a war, deployed into Wildfly 9.

I do have a beans.xml placed in WEB-INF.

The web-app version in web.xml is 3.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Session bean:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
@Path(UserRestService.RESOURCE_PATH)
public class UserRestService {

public static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "user";

@EJB
private SingletonEJB singleton;
...

@GET
@Path("/test")
public Response test() {

    if(singleton==null) {
        System.out.println("Singleton is null");
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Singleton:

```
@Startup
@LocalBean
@Singleton
public class SingletonEJB {

public SingletonEJB() {     
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> constructor");
}
```

In the wildfly log I can see the JNDI names for both beans:

```
16:57:30,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserRestService in deployment unit deployment "rest.war" are as follows:

    java:global/rest/UserRestService!com.test.rest.UserRestService
    java:app/rest/UserRestService!com.test.rest.UserRestService
    java:module/UserRestService!com.test.rest.UserRestService
    java:global/rest/UserRestService
    java:app/rest/UserRestService
    java:module/UserRestService

16:57:30,176 INFO  org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor](MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named SingletonEJB in deployment unit deployment "rest.war" are as follows:

    java:global/rest/SingletonEJB!com.test.rest.singletons.SingletonEJB
    java:app/rest/SingletonEJB!com.test.rest.singletons.SingletonEJB
    java:module/SingletonEJB!com.test.rest.singletons.SingletonEJB
    java:global/rest/SingletonEJB
    java:app/rest/SingletonEJB
    java:module/SingletonEJB
```

And I can see the constructor for the singleton is run.
The singleton does not implement any interfaces but is annotated @LocalBean

I've read countless posts all over, have looked at [this example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/jersey-ejb/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jersey_ejb/resources/MessageBoardResourceBean.java) yet I haven't figured it out...

**LE**: Added an Eclipse importable simplified demo [here](https://github.com/gandesc/non-working-jersey-ejb-injection)

Comment: Are you packaging the JAX-RS implementation in your WAR?  If yes, then I suspect this is interfering with the EJB injection.

Comment: Everything is packed into one WAR. Could be, OTOH, the jersey-ejb example that I mentioned above is also packaging everything into one war archive. This is really bugging me.

Comment: Show the code where you check that the injected `@Singleton` ejb is null.

Comment: I've updated the code of the stateless bean. I'm calling that service (method) from Postman

Comment: I have omitted the Resteasy config parameters, because I use Jersey (what does it happen if you omit them as well?), and I have accessed the REST service by navigating to the path with a web browser. The code works fine, the `@Singleton` ejb is injected correctly and is not null. I doubt it's a WildFly issue (it would be too big). Therefore I suspect this isn't a true [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test, @perissf. I have provided a fully importable project [here](https://github.com/gandesc/non-working-jersey-ejb-injection). I don't use RESTeasy either, those params inside web.xml are for disabling it, otherwise, it's bundled & enabled by default on Wildfly.

Comment: What's the server's log?